# How to properly using and implement a "Factory pattern design" in a NodeJS tool module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Based on a more significant project I'm trying to learn the "Factory design pattern" in a smaller version of it.

I prepared a snippet included at the bottom of the question ([also on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-hill-ro0ehh?file=/validator.spec.js)).

I added also the unit tests which locally on my machine are passing but on the snippet, I don't understand how to run it. By the way, the project is a running project and can be forked or copy-paste to make it run locally.

The idea is to understand how may I make it right for the Factory pattern and implement it with the best practices.

My first try at the snippets was my first idea but I would like to understand how to make it better.

Some details on the project:

The module has two flows

1. Extractor
2. Validator

The module's purpose is as a tool to validate answers or questions based on a set of rules called `eligibilityCriteria`.

**Flow 1**

you can see how it works by examining the `extractor.spec.js` on the snippet above.

The purpose of the extractor is to take 2 params

1. eligibilityCriteria -> as a string from an API a group set of rules which makes a question eligible and valid
2. question -> a type and key of a question

The question has a `type` that identifies what is the kind of question for example `yesNo` question but there are several other types. Please check the `validator.js` for it.

The `key` serves to match the specific question with its eligibilityCriteria from the other param.

EligilityCriteria comes with 1 or more sets of rules for all the questions in a questionnaire so is necessary to match the specific question with its key inside the eligibilityCriteria set.

The extractor based on the type of the question will output the specific rule/s for that specific question in an `[{}]` for every rule matching that question

A simple example to show what is the expected output for a simple yesNo type question

```
 const eligibilityCriteria = `[{
      "age":{"min":"18","max":"65"},
      "pain":{"min":"5", "max":"10"},
      "disease":{"valid":["MDD","PTSD"],"invalid":["None"]},
      "pathologies":{"valid":["FRT"],"invalid":[]},
      "medicines":"true",
      "bmi":{"min":"25","max":"100"},
      "weight":"90",
      "gender":["1","2","3"],
      "agegroup":["1","2","3"],
      "pressure": "100",
      "smoker":"20",
      "zip":"^w+s{1}w+$",
      "onlyminormax": {"min":"100","max": 0}
    }, {
      "age":{"min":"16","max":"18"},
      "pain":{"min":0, "max":"10"},
      "bmi":{"min":"10", "max":"85"},
      "fatmass":{"min":"15", "max":"25"},
      "disease":{"valid":["None"],"invalid":["PTT", "ADT", "OLL"]},
      "weight":"70",
      "gender":["1"],
      "pressure": "10",
      "diagnosis":["bipolar","depression"],
      "onlyminormax": {"min": 0,"max": "12"}
    }]`; 

const question = {
      key: "medicines",
      type: "yesno",
    };

extractor(eligibilityCriteria, question);

result [{ valid: "true" }, { valid: null }]
```

The resulting output comes from matching the `key: "medicines"` with the same key on the `eligibilityCriteria rules` as the question has only one group with the matching key the second group output is just `valid: null`. The `valid` is about identifying if the yesNo question will be valid when `true or false` which are values made by the client in the setup process of the questionnaire. Are just strings.

**Flow 2**

The validator is a tool to validate by a Boolean if an answer to a question, matches the validation rules on how the answer should be for a specific question.

to see the validation check the `validateQuestionType` method and you will see for each type how is validated.

This validation purpose is to not allow the client to set up a wrong rule for an answer in the client and so create an issue in the questionnaire output.

The `validator.psec.js` in the snippet can be consulted to see how that should work.

My idea was to make the above using also an Interface to facilitate the use of the question types and not only `validate` and `serialize` but my knowledge and experiences on that ended with my first try.

Looking forward to seeing good solutions on how to make good use of this Factory pattern.

If any questions will be in the comments I'll try to answer and add more details if something is not clear.

the snippet

```
const { get, isEmpty } = require("lodash");

const QuestionTypeInterface = {
  validate: () => {
    throw "must implement validate";
  },
  serialize: () => {
    throw "must implement serialize";
  },
};

const validateQuestionType = ({ type, eligibility, answer }) => {
  const regExp = new RegExp(eligibility);
  if (type === "yesno") return String(eligibility) === String(answer);
  if (type === "equals") return Number(eligibility) === Number(answer);
  if (type === "bigger") return Number(eligibility) <= Number(answer);
  if (type === "smaller") return Number(eligibility) >= Number(answer);
  if (type === "text") return regExp.test(answer);
  if (type === "between" || type === "bmi" || type === "scale") {
    const min = get(eligibility, "min", 0);
    const max = get(eligibility, "max", Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);
    return Number(answer) >= Number(min) && Number(answer) <= Number(max);
  }
  if (type === "select" || type === "radio") {
    return (
      Array.isArray(eligibility) &&
      (eligibility.includes(answer) || eligibility.length < 1)
    );
  }
  if (type === "checkbox") {
    const answerObj = typeof answer === "string" ? JSON.parse(answer) : answer;
    const valid = get(eligibility, "valid", []);
    const invalid = get(eligibility, "invalid", []);
    const answers = Object.keys(answerObj || {}).filter((k) => answerObj[k]);
    return (
      valid.every((v) => answers.includes(v)) &&
      !answers.some((v) => invalid.includes(v))
    );
  }
};

const singleSelectCriteria = ({ eligibility }) => {
  return eligibility.map(({ criteria }) => ({
    valid: Array.isArray(criteria) ? criteria.join() : criteria,
  }));
};

class SingleSelectQuestionType {
  constructor({ type, eligibility, answer }) {
    this.validate = () => validateQuestionType({ type, eligibility, answer });
    this.serialize = () => singleSelectCriteria({ eligibility });
  }
}
SingleSelectQuestionType.prototype = QuestionTypeInterface;

const rangeCriteria = ({ eligibility }) => {
  return eligibility.map((obj) => {
    if (!obj || !obj.criteria) {
      return { valid: null };
    }

    const { min, max } = obj.criteria;
    // * String(...) is necessary to avoid undefined due that in DB 0 is saved as 0 and not '0'
    return { valid: `${String(min)} - ${String(max)}` };
  });
};

class RangeQuestionTypes {
  constructor({ type, eligibility, answer }) {
    this.validate = () => validateQuestionType({ type, eligibility, answer });
    this.serialize = () => rangeCriteria({ eligibility });
  }
}
RangeQuestionTypes.prototype = QuestionTypeInterface;

const checkboxCriteria = ({ eligibility }) => {
  return eligibility.map((obj) => {
    if (!obj || !obj.criteria) {
      return { valid: null };
    }
    const { valid, invalid } = obj.criteria;
    return {
      valid: !isEmpty(valid) ? valid.join() : null,
      invalid: !isEmpty(invalid) ? invalid.join() : null,
    };
  });
};

class CheckboxType {
  constructor({ type, eligibility, answer }) {
    this.validate = () => validateQuestionType({ type, eligibility, answer });
    this.serialize = () => checkboxCriteria({ eligibility });
  }
}
CheckboxType.prototype = QuestionTypeInterface;

const doValidate = ({ type, eligibility, answer }) => {
  return factory({ type, eligibility, answer }).validate();
};

const doSerialize = ({ type, eligibility }) => {
  return factory({ type, eligibility }).serialize();
};

function factory({ type, eligibility, answer }) {
  switch (type) {
    case "yesno":
    case "equals":
    case "bigger":
    case "smaller":
    case "text":
    case "select":
    case "radio":
      return new SingleSelectQuestionType({ type, eligibility, answer });
    case "between":
    case "bmi":
    case "scale":
      return new RangeQuestionTypes({ type, eligibility, answer });
    case "checkbox":
      return new CheckboxType({ type, eligibility, answer });
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown answer type '${type}'`);
  }
}

function validateOneCriteria({
  eligibilityCriteria,
  answers,
  keyTypeRelation,
}) {
  /** check every eligibility criteria to validate */
  return Object.keys(eligibilityCriteria).every((key) => {
    const eligibility = eligibilityCriteria[key];
    const answer = answers[key];
    const type = get(
      keyTypeRelation.find((kt) => kt.key === key),
      "type"
    );
    return doValidate({ type, eligibility, answer });
  });
}

function questionCriteriaKeyMatch(criteriaJson, key) {
  if (!criteriaJson || !criteriaJson.length) return null;
  return criteriaJson.map((item) => ({ criteria: item[key] || null }));
}

function eligibilityCriteriaStringList({ eligibilityCriteria, key, type }) {
  const eligibility = questionCriteriaKeyMatch(eligibilityCriteria, key);

  return eligibility
    ? doSerialize({
        eligibility,
        type,
      })
    : null;
}

function paramString(something) {
  return typeof something === "string" ? JSON.parse(something) : something;
}

/**
 * Validate answers using eligibility criteria rules.
 *
 * @param {string|Object[]} eligibilityCriteria - Eligibility criteria rules. Evaluated with OR relation.
 * @param {string} eligibilityCriteria[].key - The question id.
 * @param {string} eligibilityCriteria[].value- The expected answer.
 * @param {string|Object} answers - Answers provided by the user (candidate, participant ...).
 * @param {string} answers.key - The question id.
 * @param {string} answers.value - The answer value.
 * @param {Object[]} keyTypeRelation - Question's types. Tip: you can use directly questions from a questionnaire due to the same structure.
 * @param {string} keyTypeRelation[].key - The question id.
 * @param {string} keyTypeRelation[].type - The type (e.g. "yesno", "bmi", "select" ...)
 * @returns {boolean} - Provided answers match any eligibility criteria rule.
 */
function validateAnswers(eligibilityCriteria, answers, keyTypeRelation) {
  const criteriaJson = paramString(eligibilityCriteria);
  const answersJson = paramString(answers);
  return criteriaJson.some((criteria) =>
    validateOneCriteria({
      eligibilityCriteria: criteria,
      answers: answersJson,
      keyTypeRelation,
    })
  );
}

/**
 * Extract the eligibility criteria into a string
 *
 * @param {string|Object[]} eligibilityCriteria - Eligibility criteria rules. Evaluated with OR relation.
 * @param {string} question[].key - The question key to match the question and eligibility criteria
 * @param {string} question[].type - The question type e.g. 'yesno'
 * @returns {obj|null} - Provide the eligibility rules
 */
function eligibilityCriteriaExtractor(eligibilityCriteria, question) {
  const criteriaJson = paramString(eligibilityCriteria);
  return eligibilityCriteriaStringList({
    eligibilityCriteria: criteriaJson,
    key: question.key,
    type: question.type,
  });
}

module.exports = {eligibilityCriteriaExtractor, validateAnswers};
```

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for [codereview.SE]

Comment: I was not sure actually where if here or on review but I can make it on review then also